# how to display labels like a running sequence ? C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to do "running window" like for labels. I tried to find similar solution in the google but it got me nowhere.

EXAMPLE: 5 numbers needed to be displayed at different counter values. This was macro to my timer_Start() thus, the counter increases every 5 seconds which was set at my main form.

Display: 21 23 24 25 26

If I insert another value, eg. 23, the last 5 number should be displayed.

Display: 23 21 23 24 25 ,

However, for my code below, when I insert another value, all 5 of them will change. If i change to `if(counter == 2)`, it unable to get update when the counter == 3.

```
       int counter = 0;
        sql_cmd = sql_conn.CreateCommand();
        sql_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM temp where id=12";
            try
            {
                sql_conn.Open();
                sql_reader = sql_cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (sql_reader.Read()) // start retrieve
                {
                    if (counter >= 1)
                    {
                        this.avg1.Text = sql_reader["Temp1"].ToString();

                    }
                }
                sql_conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }
            if (counter >= 2)
            {
                avg2.Text = avg1.Text;                  
            }
            if (counter >= 3)
            {
                avg3.Text = avg2.Text;
            }
            if (counter >=  4)
            {
                avg4.Text = avg3.Text;
            }
            if (counter >=  5)
            {
                avg5.Text = avg4.Text;
                counter = 0;
            }
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There are a few things unclear to me about this question, please rephrase or explain. "like for labels", "This was macro to my timer_Start() thus,", "all 5 of them will change", "it unable to get update when the counter == 3". Also please decide whether this is about c or c#. And in order to facilitate answering your question (once the description is clearer) you should provide a [mcve].

Comment: C# is not C. Remove one tag.

Comment: The numbers are display in the labels, the codes is in my private void timer ,thus it will refresh every 5 sec which also counter++. I wanted to the number to shift right every 5 sec

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with your series of `if` statements. Simple debugging would allow you to see this, so I would suggest stepping through your code before coming here next time.  With that, your `IF` statements can be refracted out into a simple method for you to use.

```
private void UpdateLabels(string newValue) {
     avg5.Text = avg4.Text;
     avg4.Text = avg3.Text;
     avg3.Text = avg2.Text;
     avg2.Text = avg1.Text;

     avg1.Text = newValue;
}
```

What is important here is that you have the correct update order. Your original `if` statements where not in the correct order, which would be why you were having issues. If you want to see why this works, walk through both sets of code in a debugger and see how the `Label.Text` properties change.

Now you can call this new method after you get your new value from the database... Here we can update your timer code to be slightly better.

```
 sql_cmd = sql_conn.CreateCommand();
 sql_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM temp where id=12";

 string newValue = String.Empty;
 try {
      sql_conn.Open();
      sql_reader = sql_cmd.ExecuteReader();
      while (sql_reader.Read()) {
           newValue = sql_reader["Temp1"].ToString();  // store in local variable
      }
 } catch (Exception e) {
      MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
 } finally {
      sql_conn.Close();  // SqlConnection.Close should be in finally block
 }

 UpdateLabels(newValue);
```

First there is no need for a counter anymore (based off your original code you posted, it was never needed). Since `Label.Text` can accept blank strings, you can always copy the values, regardless if its the first update or one millionth.

Second you can store your database value in a temporary variable. This will allow you to update the Labels even if there is a database error. After all the database operations are finished, you then call `UpdateLabels` with your new value and you are all set.